# Updates to mobile app?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

What's the likelihood of getting an update to the mobile app (currently using iOS) to include the various review and mod tools? I know that this would be a lot of work for someone (not my area of expertise), so I have no expectations, I'm just curious if anyone here would know that... or would this be a question for *upper-management* so to speak?

I put in most of my time from mobile so that's why I ask, and it's quite clumsy (especially from iOS) to try to do reviews and such... Unless I'm twice as daft as I think I am, which is entirely possible.

*NOTE: If this question is out of scope for this meta, let me know and it's gone.* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask this on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) where it's tagged [Mobile App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-app) and/or [Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) and/or [iOS App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app). Before you post you probably want to search through these to see if your question was already asked. Also, IIRC, I think they've stopped development of the mobile apps which aren't the StackOverflow one. I think I've read it somewhere, but I could be mistaken. If you don't find what you're looking for, just ask over there ... you may get your answers.

Comment: Thanks. :) I'll leave this for now in case anyone else in the future has the same curiosity.